# SCCM query find fonts

Tags: windows, fonts, sccm

Hi I am trying to find a SCCM query that will tell me which computers on the network have a certain type of font installed on the computer.  There a list of 13 that I need to find.

BUMP

Due to knowing what fonts I need, I have configured a new software inventory list. I filtered out clvhy*.ttf in order for it to find the below fonts in

```
%windir%/Fonts

clvhy1b.ttf
clvhy1w.ttf
clvhy2b.ttf
clvhy2w.ttf
clvhy3b.ttf
clvhy3w.ttf
```

Now do I create a Query? Or how will a get my list of which computers have clvhy* fonts installed?

Answer (score 1):

From memory, I don't believe SCCM inventories font information by default. So you have a few options open to you:

1. Modify software inventory settings to inventory all *.ttf files. This could have a significant impact on the clients though, not to mention your db size. It also might not provide the information you need as it'll just get the font filenames.
2. Use software inventory to just collect the specific font files you're interested in. This is better than 1 but has the same failing if you don't know the filenames.
3. Use a DCM to specifically identify the fonts you're interested in and pass/fail accordingly. This could be implemented as a powershell/vbscript which would actually open the font files to identify them by more than just the filename, or read the information from the registry/WMI, so it could be more flexible than the other two options.

Comment: Thanks. Well I know the file names. I'll look into option 2.

Comment: I created a new software inventory. Now do I create a Query? Or how will a get my list of which computers have clvhy* fonts installed?